# Does the following limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have some trivial confusion.

In the following case, is the limit $a$? or is that the limit does not exist?
I am just trying to be **too careful** not to do something wrong. Specially when infinity is so deceitful.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{a}{n}=a?/\infty??$$

Comment: $\sum_i \frac{a}{n} = a \sum_i \frac{1}{n} = a \frac{1}{n} \sum_i 1$. This is about the series, not $a$. What is the value of $\sum_i 1$?

Comment: No. $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = 1+...+1$ ($n$ times). Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n$. And $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n = 1$.

Comment: @user1709828 It's not valid to split it up as $(\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n a) \cdot (\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n})$, but I don't see why you would want to do that anyway.  Just _evaluate_ the thing you're taking the limit of.

Comment: A you sure it is not $a \over i$ in the sum?

Comment: @Maesumi then it would not confuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers all factor out the $a$ for some reason, but it's easier just to notice that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a}{n} = \underbrace{\frac{a}{n} + \cdots + \frac{a}{n}}_{\text{$n$ times}} = n \cdot \frac{a}{n} = a,$$
so you are taking the limit of a constant sequence.  What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}a$?

By the way, I don't know if this is causing your confusion, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a}{n}$ is not the same as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a}{i}$. The latter limit is by definition the sum of the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a}{i}$, which diverges (if $a$ is nonzero.)

Answer (score 1):

Your sum is:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{a}{n}
  = a \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{n}
  = a \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1
  = a
$$